# Preg_replace problem, must be trivial

Tags: php, regex

I am obviously doing something completely wrong when it comes to preg_replace.

Say I have a string of text,

"Silence is golden until you are the one silenced." And I want to replace "Silence" with "**Silence**" but not replace the silence in silenced.

Here is the code I have in place:

```
$q = "Silence is golden until you are the one silenced.";
$card = "Silence";
$pattern = '/\b'.$card.'\b/i';
$q = preg_replace($pattern,'<strong>'.$card.'</strong>',$q);
```

This is failing and setting $q = ""

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing, not doubling the \, assuming \ means escape-character in PHP strings. Try \\b

Comment: Seems to work fine..http://www.ideone.com/on1aC

Comment: Your code works fine on PHP 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.5.

Comment: @Paul: Inside single quoted strings, only `\\‍` and `\'` are known escape sequences; any other escape sequence stays untouched. Thus `'\b' === '\\b'`.

Comment: @Gumbo, thanks. I now know slightly more about PHP :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. In the actual code I am iterating over an array of items to preg_replace and just applying preg_replace without first testing using preg_match.

Comment: You can use the replacement `'<strong>$0</strong>'` with `$0` being a backreference to the matched string of the whole regular expression pattern.